# How to use Oauth clientid using google classroom API in Android

Tags: android, google-classroom

how to add OAuth client ID in android using google classroom APIs? I want to display the list of courses.

If i use email chooses option means other people also have to login the email id its not good way to use. That's why we need to pass the oauth id in application.

This is code based on emailaccountcredential. How to change the oauth client id? I am passing created mail id,i want to pass the oauth id

```
mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                    getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))

                    .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());
            SharedPreferences settings =
                    getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, "pristine1sup@gmail.com");
            editor.apply();
            mCredential.setSelectedAccountName("pristine1sup@gmail.com");
```

Comment: please someone help me ,java code is not fully supporting

Comment: Adding "please help me" several times isn't going to improve your chances

Comment: No one is replying